# Get rails view helper methods inside coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, view-helpers

I have a view helper, let say (for simplicity's sake)

```
def call_alert
  return "alert 'this should appear'"
end
```

Then I have a coffeescript file **some_test_page.js.coffee** which renders for an action which is called via ajax.
Inside this **some_test_page.js.coffee** I have:

```
<%= call_alert %>
```

When I do an ajax call to **/some_test_page**, I usually would expect to get a response with the compiled javascript from the coffeescript file and an alert would occur. However, it seems the view helper I tried to use cannot be accessed.

If I put a simple

```
alert 'this should appear'
```

inside my some_test_page.js.coffee file it works fine.

I feel like this should be ok, but maybe I'm doing something counter-convention or stupid?

How can I get the view helpers from application_helper.rb inside my coffeescript view files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the issue was that the javascript inside my helper method wasn't adding newlines to the js it was returning *doh*.

As a result, Coffeescript was trying to compile one huge string of unseparated code statements.
I added \n to my js code lines in the helper and everything works fine now.